# How to host ASP.NET Core web-app inside an Apache website?

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, .net-core, yii2, centos7

I have an old `php` application developed using the `Yii2` framework hosted on a `Centos` server at the path `/var/www/html`. This application is accessible at `http://somedomain.com/`.

I am working on new API project developed using `ASP.NET MVC Core` which needs to be accessible at `http://somedomain.com/v2/`.

So, is it possible to host the `dotnet core` application inside an `Apache` site and have both of them work at the same time? If yes, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: you want to host both on same server?

Comment: @Amir yes, I want to host both on the same server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a reverse proxy to do that. Let's say your `ASP.NET Core` app runs on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` by:

```
dotnet run --urls=http://localhost:5000
```

if the request start with `http://somedomain.com/v2/`, then proxy to the `ASP.NET Core App`.

```
+-------+
|       +----------------------------------------+
|       |                                        |
|       |           PHP module                   |
|       |                                        |
|       +----------------------------------------+
|Apache2|
|       |
|  (80) |                   +--------------------+
|       | start with /v2/   |                    |
|       |                   |   Asp.Net Core App |
|       +------------------->                    |
|       |                   |     (5000)         |
|       |  reverse proxy    |                    |
+-------+                   +--------------------+
```

Firstly, configure proxy module by **uncomment these lines** in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_http2_module modules/mod_proxy_http2.so
```

And then **add the following reverse proxy settings for requests that start with `/v2/`**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /v2/ http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://somedomain.com/
    ServerName somedomain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapp1-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}webapp1-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it should work as expected.

**A working Demo**

Here's a demo that listens on `8089` instead of `80`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the awesome answer. I was able to successfully implement this on both development and staging servers. However, the production server is running an HTTPS site and I'm getting 404 even after following these steps. Do we need to make any extra steps here?