# How to configure apache as a reverse proxy for asp.net core

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, centos, web-deployment, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to deploy aspo.net core MVC application to a linux server - centos - with apache as a reverse proxy, and so far i was following this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2

and i tried to run the application on the server to make sure that it's working, and it said that *port 5000* is in use, so i changed the port by this code in the **program.cs** file ...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 9009);
            })
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .Build();
```

and it ran in the server on port 9009 
but the problem is that i can't access it.
i tried to access by the ip address *138.201.131.247:9009*
and tried to access by the domain name *http://medicalrecords.host:9009*
even i tried to ping to it through terminal with

```
ping 127.0.0.1:9009
```

it shows this message

```
[root@server ~]# ping 127.0.0.1:9009
ping: 127.0.0.1:9009: Name or service not known
```

but nothing work
and i tried to configure apache to working as a reverse proxy by this code

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9009/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9009/
    ServerName medicalrecords.host
    ServerAlias medicalrecords.host
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/testapp-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/testapp-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

and also not working.
*** Note That *** there are multiple domain running on this apache server as it serving them and it configured by domain name, i don't know if this is the problem or not but i tried every thing but not the solution :D.
Thanks alot.

Comment: 1. Your `ping 127.0.0.1:9009` **won't work**. Use `wget http://127.0.0.1:9009` to test  it instead. 2. Did you enable the proxy modules of apache?  3. Sometimes it doesn't work with `127.0.0.1`, you can try to make the kestrel listening on `0.0.0.0` with `opts.ListenAnyIP(9009);`,

Comment: 1. thank you, i tried it with this and it worked it respond with ok.

Comment: 2. i don't know how to enable this module, but if you need to know the apache is working on other apps so if this is a must thing to do to serve application, perhaps it's already done, but tell me how to do it

Comment: "but tell me how to do it ": Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779013/how-to-host-a-dotnet-core-web-app-inside-an-apache-website/56788295#56788295

Comment: 3.you want me to change every `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` even in configuration file for apache ???

Comment: No. Sometimes a server might contains multiple network interface cards. If you make your kestrel only accepts request from `127.0.0.1`, it might fail to receive incoming messages from other NICs. Just make your kestrel listens on `0.0.0.0`. Your Apache is designed to be exposed to the public, there's no need to change it to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: the link tell me to open file and change something in it  `load module .....` make it uncomment but apache when i open this file tells me not to change anything in it beacuse it's auto generated, and any way id didn't find the `load module ...` in this file anyway

Comment: Please run `httpd -M` to ensure you've enabled these modules.

Comment: `proxy_module (shared)`
`proxy_fcgi_module (shared)`
`proxy_http_module (shared)`
`proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)` these module has appeared when i enter `httpd -M` i think this mean that it's not that ... some guys tell me that the firewall block the access to that port from outside ??? could it be that . and how to check

Comment: I believe it is not caused by firewall because there're multiple domain running on the same server. By the way,You should access `http://medicalrecords.host` (without `:9009`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe the problem was the port specified in the apache configuration, it was the same for apache general request, i changed it to 90 and it worked fine for me, along with the answer @itminus said to change that line in the API `opts.ListenAnyIP(9009);` to listen to any default port in the server. Thanks alot.